# Supplementary development tools for Java

Tags: java, supplementary

What are your favorite supplementary tools for Java development?

Mine are:

1) Total Commander (due to the ability to search inside JARs).

2) JAD + Jadclipse  (to understand and debug libraries)

And of-course, Google. (can't really live without it)

Answer (score 4):

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

PMD scans Java source code and looks for potential problems like:

```
* Possible bugs - empty try/catch/finally/switch statements
* Dead code - unused local variables, parameters and private methods
* Suboptimal code - wasteful String/StringBuffer usage
* Overcomplicated expressions - unnecessary if statements, for loops that could be while loops
* Duplicate code - copied/pasted code means copied/pasted bugs
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jython](http://www.jython.org/) for interactive testing and exploration of all sorts of things.

Answer (score 3):

- Eclipse Classic (with WebTools, Subclipse and Eclipse Checkstyle plugins)
- Maven
- Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 3):

- Eclipse
- TextMate
- Ant
- Maven
- JUnit and friends
- Checkstyle (plugins for Eclipse and Maven)
- JAD
- DBVisualizer

Answer (score 2):

1. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) for organizing and building your project
2. [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) to do this automatically ;-)
3. [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net) (and the [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org) plugin for Eclipse) to get some insight in your code coverage

Answer (score 2):

1. Ultra Edit
2. Agent Ransack
3. DJ Java Decompiler

Answer (score 1):

[JavaRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/javarebel/features/) speeds up development by automatically hot deploying code changes to the running program.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much spend most of my time in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and at the command line.

With Eclipse I usually modify the keyboard bindings so I have features such as Open Type/Resource, Quick Outline, Show Refactor Menu and so on at the tip of my fingers. I also install [Q for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/q4e/) to enable good Maven-integration allowing me access to the source of my dependencies when coding.

At the command line it's tools such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) that are used the most. I have a few commands to switch between JDKs to test that projects compile and run on all their intended targets.

I used to keep a copy of JAD around, but thanks to Maven and Q for Eclipse I harldy ever use it anymore. Decompiled code is not nearly as usable as the original.

I almost forgot, JConsole helps with monitoring your application also I use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com) for more advanced profiling.

Answer (score 1):

- Eclipse with:

  - Subclipse
  - JBoss Tools
  - Ant
  - Junit
- Ultraedit (for column editing)
- JAD
- Jarbrowser
- SQLYog (for MySQL), TOAD (for Oracle), Management Studio (for SQL Server)

Eclipse has already a lot to offer, thanks to the countless plugins (which support other languages and environments, too).

Answer (score 1):

- Ant/Maven
- TextMate
- Google of course ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Groovy: my pseudo Java scratchpad
2. Eclipse or Netbeans: whichever I am feeling like for an IDE
3. Subversion: always need a good version control

Answer (score 0):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Apparently this is the wrong answer.  So perhaps somebody could tell me what are my favourite supplementary development tools?